# delphi android indy udp server not receiving in a mobile network

Tags: android, delphi, mobile, udp, indy

The objective is sending just a string from a Windows PC computer to a mobile Android connected to a 3G network.

I know the external IP of the mobile.  And I have two firemonkey programs, the server and the client. The client just writes in a memo the string that it receives.

Code is so simple:

Client:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    form1.IdUDPClient1.Send('Hi there');
  end;
```

Server:

```
procedure TForm1.IdUDPServer1UDPRead(AThread: TIdUDPListenerThread;
const AData: TIdBytes; ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
 var
 entrada : string;
 begin
   entrada := bytestoString(Adata);
   form1.Memo1.Lines.Add('I have received = '+entrada);
   form1.Memo1.GoToTextEnd;

 end;
```

This works in my house, internal IPs.

It does not work in the mobile if connected to a 3G network. However, if the server is in the PC and the client in the mobile, I can send a string to the PC even the mobile is connected to the 3G network.

So I can access to the PC, but I cannot access to the mobile phone.

I have disabled antivirus and windows firewall in the PC.

Maybe the mobile company is blocking something? 
ports are closed in mobile phones?

Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please add the current IP of the mobile device in 3G network (the first three numbers are enough)

Comment: Thanks four your help: IP of the mobile is 5.40.162.XXX

Comment: My God, if I make a ping to my phone IP address... all the packets are lost. So the provider is closing the inbound connections I guess.

Comment: Not closing it, but blocking it. When your server is on the device and your client is on your PC, that data is inbound to the device. The provider is likely blocking that. Ask the provider. Also make sure your Android app has the `INTERNET` permission.

Comment: So my company does not want to unblock a port. It says that I would need a fixed IP and they are not offering this service. I will find another solution.